# Validating mobile number with specific rules

Tags: php, validation, mobile

I am trying to work out the best way to validate a mobile number.  The issue is that I have to insert this number into an external system, and currently some things are causing it to fail.  I have some basic validation on the frontend which makes sure it is less than 20, and can contain digits, +, - and ().  Although I am validating a mobile, the mobile could be located in any country which is why I am allowing a few other characters.

The issue is, these additional characters apart from the + can't be inserted into this external system (they are used in my own database though).  So to start with, I remove them

```
$phone = str_replace([' ', '-', '(', ')'], '', $this->mobile);
```

Next rule is, if its a UK number, to remove the starting 0 from the number if provided

```
if (substr($phone, 0, 4) === '+440') {
    $this->mobile = str_replace('+440', '+44', $phone);
}
```

So if all is well at this point, I know that a UK number will be 13 characters in length (after adding the +44 and removing the 0)

To handle different cases (they didnt use +44, or it is an international mobile) I added the following

```
if (strlen($phone) !== 13) {
    $lastTen = substr($phone, -10);
    $prefix = substr($phone, 0, 3);
    if($prefix === '+44') {
        $this->mobile = $prefix . $lastTen;
    } elseif (substr($phone, 0, 1) === '+') {
        $this->mobile = $phone;
    } else {
        $this->mobile = '+44' . $lastTen;
    }
}
```

So if its not 13 characters in length, I take the last ten and first three characters.  If it starts +44, I append the last 10 onto this.  Reason I do this is that I noticed that a lot of times people seem to repeat themselves e.g. +447711+447711222222 (the +44 has a seperate input field to the main body of the number)

If it starts with a plus, but it is not +44, I assume it is an international number so I do not touch it.

If it doesnt start with a plus, I just take the last 10 and append it to a +44 (most cases it will be a UK number)

So things currently work ok, but there are cases where additional pluses make it into the final string.

Really I was looking into advice as to how I can clean things up a bit more, and make sure that there is only one plus at the start of the string?

Thanks

Comment: It would be better to include an example of the text and what you expect the result to look like

Comment: What??? `If it doesnt start with a plus, I just take the last 10 and append it to a +44 (most cases it will be a UK number)` So all that work and you just destroy it all with this? What if the user forgot one digit? This rule alone will destroy the rules and the phone number.

Comment: It is difficult to include what it should look like because I dont know how internal numbers will look.  But it will be something like +44772266337722, so starts with a plus, followed by maximum 19 digits.  I can't tell if user forgets 1 digit because it may be international, and these can be any length. From what I have seen, the last 10 digits generally contain the correct number if appended to +44.  90% of numbers are UK, but I still need to try my best to handle international numbers.  Thanks

Comment: @kate or you just use whatever the user inputs. Most of the times forms can be auto completed, if you allow auto complete then it should be ok. If you don't allow it, you either have to trust the user, validate with SMS for example or do some crazy code that may or may not work to validate and sanitize the number.